# remove selected (highlighted elements) except for input#cursor

Tags: javascript

I have this function which removes selected (cursor) highlighted elements:

```
function deleteSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // Mozilla
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            window.getSelection().deleteFromDocument();
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    } else if (document.selection) {
        // Internet Explorer
        var ranges = document.selection.createRangeCollection();
        for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
            ranges[i].text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

What I actually want to do is remove all the cursor- highlighted elements, except for the input#cursor element.

edit:

so lets say if I highlighted these elements with my cursor:

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<input type='text' id = 'cursor' />
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
```

on a keyup, this function should not remove the `<input>` ...only the `<span>`

Comment: Oish. How about Google? `:not()`, `.not()`?

Comment: this is for a jquery function, Im looking for a pure javascript solution that is similar to .not(). Maybe I should change the tag :p sorry

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, that was a little harder than expected!

Here's the code, I've tested it in IE8 and Chrome 16/FF5. The JSFiddle I used to test is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GvaKY/20/). AFAIK, this is probably the best performance-wise you'll get.

The docs I used for Moz: [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection), [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Range), [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DocumentFragment). IE: [TextRange](http://www.webreference.com/js/column12/trmethods.html)

```
function deleteSelection() {
    // get cursor element
    var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');

    // mozilla
    if(window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var containsCursor = selection.containsNode(cursor, true);

        if(containsCursor) {
            var cursorFound = false;
            for(var i=0; i < selection.rangeCount; i++) {
                var range = selection.getRangeAt(i);
                if(!cursorFound) {                 
                    // extracts tree from DOM and gives back a fragment
                    var contents = range.extractContents();
                    // check if tree fragment contains our cursor
                    cursorFound = containsChildById(contents, 'cursor');
                    if(cursorFound) range.insertNode(cursor); // put back in DOM
                }
                else {
                    // deletes everything in range
                    range.deleteContents();
                }
            }  
        }
        else {
            selection.deleteFromDocument();
        }
        // removes highlight   
        selection.removeAllRanges();
    }
    // ie
    else if(document.selection) {
        var ranges = document.selection.createRangeCollection();
        var cursorFound = false;
        for(var i=0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
            if(!cursorFound) {
                // hacky but it will work
                cursorFound = (ranges[i].htmlText.indexOf('id=cursor') != -1);
                if(cursorFound)
                    ranges[i].pasteHTML(cursor.outerHTML); // replaces html with parameter
                else
                    ranges[i].text = '';
            }
            else {
                ranges[i].text = '';
            }
        }
    }
}

// simple BFS to find an id in a tree, not sure if you have a 
// library function that does this or not
function containsChildById(source, id) {
    q = [];
    q.push(source);

    while(q.length > 0) {
        var current = q.shift();
        if(current.id == id)
            return true;

        for(var i=0; i < current.childNodes.length; i++) {
            q.push(current.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1. I agree with the approach (my answer uses the same), though the branch for older IE is horribly hacky. Also, why `createRangeCollection()` rather than just `createRange()`? IE selections have never supported multiple text selections, so you can simplify by using `createRange()`, although you need to check that the selection has `type` "Text" first.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the element you want keep, extracting the contents of the selection using Range's `extractContents()` method and then reinserting the element you want to keep using the range's `insertNode()` method.

For IE < 9, which doesn't support DOM Range, the code is trickier, so for simplicity you could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library, which also adds convenience methods such as the `containsNode()` method of Range.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DFxH8/1/

Code:

```
function deleteSelectedExcept(node) {
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount, range, nodeInRange; i < len; ++i) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(i);
            nodeInRange = range.containsNode(node);
            range.extractContents();
            if (nodeInRange) {
                range.insertNode(node);
            }
        }
    }
}

deleteSelectedExcept(document.getElementById("cursor"));
```